# Python attrs validator and __attrs_post_init__() are not called

Tags: python, attr

I created a class using @attr.s and defined an attribute validator and **attrs_post_init**() method. I expect these methods to be automatically called when instantiating an object of this class. But these do not seem to be called at all anytime before or after **init**().

```
import attr
from typeguard import typechecked
from typing import Any, Optional

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True, init=False)
class Entry:
    name: Optional[str] = attr.ib()

    @typechecked
    def __init__(
        self, name: Optional[str] = None
    ):
        print("Entered init")
        self.name = name

    @name.validator
    def name_validator(self, _attribute: Any, value: Optional[str]) -> None:
        print("Entered validator")

    def __attrs_post_init__(self) -> None:
        print("Entered post")
        
Entry("Bob")
```

This only prints `Entered init`.

When do the attribute validator and attrs_post_init() method get called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attrs` cannot perform work at object construction time unless you let it handle object construction. The things you are expecting to happen would normally happen in the generated `__init__` method, but you turned that off.

By rejecting the generated `__init__` and implementing your own, *you* have taken responsibility for these tasks. If you want validation, *you* need to do it. If you want `__attrs_post_init__` to be called, *you* need to call it.